# Use of undeclared identifier 'target_'; did you mean '_target'?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

in my xcode project with cocos2d framework i imported an external class;
i added the .h in my layer and i added the .m of the external class into compile source but the message is the same
Use of undeclared identifier 'target_'; did you mean '_target'?

Thanks

Comment: if you don't synthesis your accessors and don't declare a property named target_ in your .h xcode will generate a generic _target property for any @property (strong/weak/assign) id target

Comment: but i've another project than i downloaded from the internet where the same class is imported and there isn't property named target_

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the project you downloaded is not up to date with the current 2.x branch of cocos2d. Some time ago instance variables were renamed from `variable_` to the ObjC/Cocoa customary prefix with leading underscore: `_variable`

Which means you'll have to upgrade the code you downloaded and fix these issues.